# Execute Mobx store action when flutter app loads

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I'm using `Mobx` for manage my states in `flutter` app. Written store action is there to get data from local storage and add to my `Mobx` store. For that I needs to execute that action each time when app loads so that data is available for user when app loading is complete.

What is the best way to approach this ?

I've already tried this. but I can't access context in `initState()`.

```
class Navigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationState createState() => _NavigationState();
}

class _NavigationState extends State<Navigation> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final studentStore = Provider.of<StudentStore>(context); // Here I can't access context

    @override
     void initState() {
     super.initState();
     studentStore.addExistingData(); // This is where I'm trying to execute action
   } 

  changeRoute(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _widgetOptios = <Widget>[
      WelcomeScreen(),
      Reports(),
      Text("History"),
      Text("Settings"),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: _widgetOptios.elementAt(currentIndex)),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomTabNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: currentIndex, onTap: changeRoute),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

didChangeDependencies is the method where context is available for the first time. Right after initState, after all the dependencies are loaded.

```dart
  late StudentStore _studentStore;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() { 

    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _studentStore = Provider.of<StudentStore>(context);  // you can get context here
  
    // access your methods
    _studentStore.addExistingData();

  }
```